# Removing context menu entry in Eclipse PDE using Activities

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I am using `org.eclipse.ui.activities` to remove certain context menu entries.
I was successful in removing

> Team, Show in Remote Systems View, Restore From Local History

by using the below in my plugin.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin> 
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
<activity description="Disable Menu/Context Menu Contributions"
    id="com.myapp.myactivity" name="MyViewActivity">
</activity>

<activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity"
    pattern="org.eclipse.team.*"/>

    <activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity"
    pattern="org.eclipse.rse.*"/>

    <activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity"
    pattern="org.eclipse.compare.*"/>

</extension>
</plugin>
```

I need to remove the "Profile As" , "Source" , "Configure" entries. I've used plugin spy of eclipse and was able to get the associated class and it's plugin jar like for e.x

```xml
<activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity" 
    pattern="org\.eclipse\.ui\.workbench/org\.eclipse\.jst\.servlet\.ui\.internal\.actions\.ConvertToWebModuleTypeAction"/>
```

for Removing Configure->Convert To Dynamic Web Project Entry in the context menu but this doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

From Plugin Spy

```
The active contribution item identifier:
convertToWebModuleTypeAction
The active contribution location URI:
menu:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=convertToWebModuleTypeAction
The active contribution item class:
ConvertToWebModuleTypeAction
The contributing plug-in:
org.eclipse.ui.workbench (3.7.1.v20120104-1859)
```

Any Help to remove the entries above (i.e Profile As, Source, Configure) will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's not really the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plugin that contributes this, I don't know why that's reported.  I'd try and track down the `org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui` plugin.xml somewhere under http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/jeetools/plugins/?root=WebTools_Project

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will try that out and let you know...